# index out of range exception in datagridview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

following is the code which i have used while selecting the particular rows column value on pressing the F9 key.but i get the error as argument out of range exception was handled.detailed error comes as index out of range exception.

```
Private Sub dgsearchitemlist_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, _
       ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) _
       Handles dgsearchitemlist.KeyDown

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.F9 Then
        itemcode = dgsearchitemlist.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value

        description = dgsearchitemlist.SelectedRows(0).Cells(2).Value.ToString
        uom = dgsearchitemlist.SelectedRows(0).Cells(3).Value.ToString

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: How many columns are in your gridview and on which line the error came up?

Comment: that will happen if there are no SelectedRows or if you have fewer columns than you are referencing

Comment: the error came in the first line itself..itemcode = dgsearchitemlist.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value

Comment: i am refering the first column..there are 3 columns in the gridview

Comment: if there are only 3 columns, then Cells(3) is out of range (0, 1, 2) = 3

Comment: but then why its showing in the first column itself...cells(0)..also i have commented out the last two lines..but still it shows in the first one

Comment: Try to comment out the cells(0) line and see what happens. Or are there rows in the first place?

Comment: @vimalvasudevan it IS possible there is more than one thing broken.  If there are 3 columns only, it WILL error out at `Cells(3)`; if there are no rows selected, `SelectedRows(0)` will cause an error.

Comment: Can you post the complete error message you're receiving?

Comment: yes there are rows present...If dgsearchitemlist.SelectedRows.Count = 0  Then Exit Sub is always returning true even when i am selecting the rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Alternative 1:

Perhaps dgsearchitemlist.SelectionMode is NOT SET to either **RowHeaderSelect** or **FullRowSelect**. *Manually selecting all the cells of a row does not select that row*. please check and set the property to any of these values.

### Alternative 2:

If you need just the last selected row, then you can use **dgsearchitemlist.CurrentRow** instead of dgsearchitemlist.SelectedRows(0). Then you don't have to check whether any rows have been selected or not.

Hope any of these alternatives will click !

Comment: thanks man..you solution is just what the doctor ordered.yes i was searching for that only..i need only one value to be fetched on the F9 key event.thanks a lot yaar..the code is working fine now

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you reference a column index that does not exist, in this case it could be either of this code:

```
  description = dgsearchitemlist.SelectedRows(0).Cells(2).Value.ToString
  uom = dgsearchitemlist.SelectedRows(0).Cells(3).Value.ToString
```

That is Cells(2) or Cell(3). If you have only two columns and you have index of 2 that means you are accessing column 3 and if you have an index 3 it means you are accessing column 4. And any of those columns does not exist then it would be index out of range.

Comment: above lines are not giving error as it shows in cells(0) itself..also i have commented out these lines..description = dgsearchitemlist.SelectedRows(0).Cells(2).Value.ToString
  uom = dgsearchitemlist.SelectedRows(0).Cells(3).Value.ToString

Comment: @vimalvasudevan could it be that there are no rows to select in the first place? And the error comes from `SelectedRows(0)`?

Comment: but why no rows are being selected even when i am selecting the rows

Comment: Are you using multi-threading or is there any thread running in the background?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like maybe in some cases, there are no rows selected.  try this:

```
Private Sub dgsearchitemlist_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) _
    Handles dgsearchitemlist.KeyDown

    If dgsearchitemlist.SelectedRows.Count = 0  Then Exit Sub

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.F9 Then
        itemcode = dgsearchitemlist.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value
        ...
```

Comment: now when i am in debug mode..the statement if dgsearchitemlist.SelectedRows.Count = 0  Then Exit Sub is always coming true even if i am selecting the rows... is something wrong with the event handler

Comment: could there be other code be unselecting rows before this code runs?

Comment: set a do nothing break in the selectionchanged event to be sure.  something is clearing your selection which explains the original error (it doesnt have to be your code, it could be a DGV method).

Comment: how to set the do nothing break.

Comment: `console.writeline("DGV row selection changed")` - **NOT** a messagebox! with a break on that line, you can look at the stack to see what is deselecting, without a break you can see if it is happening in the output window.  `Dim i AS integer = 0` is another example

Comment: yes you are right the  Private Sub dgsearchitemlist_SelectionChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles dgsearchitemlist.SelectionChanged
        Console.WriteLine("DGV row selection changed")
    End Sub is getting fired..now how should i disable it..

Comment: FInd out WHY and WHERE and from WHAT the selection is being tampered with - look at the call stack.  you might have more important code clearing it for a good reason.

Comment: confused now about how. theres no other code clearing it...kindly guide on how to remove the event handler

Comment: removing the event handler will not get rid of the problem - the selection will still change - the event is simply TELLING YOU that the selection did change. you must find out from the call stack where this is happening.  Note: it will fire legitimately when you select some rows, you want to trace back thru the call stack when it fires AFTER you select some and before your F9 code runs.

Comment: :how to find the call stack...i am a newbie hence this question

Comment: Debug Menu -> Windows -> Call Stack  .. or maybe Ctl-L (may depend on your VS version).

Comment: call stack is having no problems.

Comment: I dont know what you expected - it doesnt report problems - but when it stops the second time - before it gets to the F9 press, the call stack will tell you where it has been.  you need to examine each procedure to see which one is changing the selection.  we are WELL into a whole new issue now and need to break this off - I cant really teach you how to debug a program I cant see in comments, sorry.  Hope this helped - and check this off, please...